# deleting element from a string list

Tags: c++

Hi I've been stuck for a while. I'm trying to delete element from a list by using erase

```
for (auto it = list.begin; it != list.end();) {
        if (true) {
            
        } else {
            it = list.erase(it);
            it++;
        }
    }
```

but the list turns out to be something like

```
1.apple
2.banana
3.
4.
```

and I want to get rid of the empty element. I saw one post saying I should use `list.erase(list.begin()+k)` but the compiler says there's some problem with operator `+`. I guess it means I didn't define it or it conflicts with something else. Is there any other ways I could get rid of the empty elements?

Comment: That loop does nothing, please post real code. Also please clarify some details, for example what `list` is, probably `std::list`? It may be a better question if you just post your attempt that you described below along with the error message.

Comment: `list.begin() + k` won't compile because list iterator doesn't support `+` operation (it is not a random access iterator). Use `std::next(list.begin(), k)`.

Comment: [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) with a suitable [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to check for empty strings? Don't forget the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase–remove_idiom).

Comment: Typo? `list.begin` should be `list.begin()` (in `it` initialization)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, why use erase-remove for lists? `std::list` has its own `remove_if` member function that erases elements.

Comment: As documented, `erase()` returns the iterator to the element after the one deleted, already, so why do you then `++it` too? It looks like you've cut and pasted random bits of code together. That's not a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

With the assumption that `list` is a `std::list<std::string>` where you want to remove all empty strings it is as easy as calling `std::list::remove` like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> list { /* some values here */};
    list.remove({});
}
```

Alternatively

```
list.remove("");
```

might be more readable.

#### Short Explanation

- `list.remove` expects an parameter of type `std::string` and will remove all values in the list that are eqivalent to this parameter.
- passing `{}` will construct an empty string as parameter
- passing `""` does basically the same
- thus it will remove all values that are equal to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. First, I've edited your source code, it shows how to use `list::erase`.

```
#include <string>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> list;

    for (auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end();) {
        if (*it == "string-to-delete") {
            it = list.erase(it);
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Second: use `std::remove`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> list;

    auto it = std::remove(list.begin(), list.end(), "string-to-delete");
    list.erase(it, list.end());

    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

3. you can use `std::remove_if`.
4. you can use `std::list::remove(...)` as mentioned churill

Comment: There is absolutely no point using `std::remove_if()` with a lambda that just compares to a constant value... `std::remove(value)` exists, as does `list.remove(value)`.